# Kubernetes. What happens if the request size is greater than the pod's RAM?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I don't understand how replication works in Kubernetes.

I understand that two replicas on different nodes will provide fault tolerance for the application, but I don’t understand this:

Suppose the application is given the following resources:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: images.my-company.example/app:v4
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "1G"
        cpu: "1"
      limits:
        memory: "1G"
        cpu: "1"
```

The application has two replicas. Thus, in total, 2 CPUs and 2G RAM are available for applications.

But what happens if the application receives a request with a size of 1.75G? After all, only 1G RAM is available in one replica. Will the request be distributed among all replicas?

**Answer for Harsh Manvar**

Maybe you misunderstood me?

What you explained is not entirely true.

Here is a real, working deployment of four replicas:

```
$ kubectl get deployment dev-phd-graphql-server-01-master-deployment
NAME                                          READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
dev-phd-graphql-server-01-master-deployment   4/4     4            4           6d15h
```

```
$ kubectl describe deployment dev-phd-graphql-server-01-master-deployment
 ...
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  4G
    Requests:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  4G
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't get distributed one replica will start simply and the other will stay in **pending** state.

If you will describe that pending POD(replica) it show this error :

```
0/1 nodes available: insufficient cpu, insufficient memory
```

> kubectl describe pod **POD-name**

K8s will check for the requested resource

```
requests:
        memory: "1G"
        cpu: "1"
```

if mentioned minimum requested resources available it will deploy the replica and other will goes in pending state.

**Update**

> But what happens if the application receives a request with a size of
> 1.75G? After all, only 1G RAM is available in one replica.

```
requests:
        memory: "1G"
        cpu: "1"
      limits:
        memory: "1G"
        cpu: "1"
```

If you have a set request of **1 GB** and application start using the **1.75 GB** it will kill or restart the POD due to hitting the limit.

But yes in some cases container might can exceeds the limit if Node has memory available.

> A Container can exceed its memory request if the Node has memory
> available. But a Container is not allowed to use more than its memory
> limit. If a Container allocates more memory than its limit, the
> Container becomes a candidate for termination. If the Container
> continues to consume memory beyond its limit, the Container is
> terminated. If a terminated Container can be restarted, the kubelet
> restarts it, as with any other type of runtime failure.

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#exceed-a-container-s-memory-limit

You might would like to read this also : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run

Comment: Please, check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

See for these kinds of circumstances you need to have an idea of how large of a request it can get and accordingly setup your resource request and limits.
If you feel there can be a request as big as 1.75GB you have tackle it in your source code.
For example you might have a conversion job which takes a lot of resources. You can make it a celery task and host the celery worker in another node group which is made for large tasks (A AWS t3.xlarge for example)
Anyways such large tasks will not generate a result immediately so I don't see a problem in running them asynchronously and giving back the result later maybe even in a websocket message. This will keep you main server from getting clumped up and also will help you to efficiently scale your large tasks